# Python tool for visual studio 2017

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I add packages in a Python application Project in visual studio 2017.

[image]

Comment: Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.  I found the answer at the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2017

In short open the python environments window which you can find in the menu under:  view -- other windows -- python environments.

[image]

If you are having trouble it is probably because the green circled combo box is set to Overview rather than packages.
First select an environment from the among the installed python environments.  I chose env1 in the red circle.  Then if the green circled combo box is set to packages the packages installed in the selected environment will show in the blue circle.
To install a package in the selected environment type the package name in the listbox where it says "search pypl and installed packages.  If intelli-sense finds the right package name double click to install your package.  When done the new package shows up with the other packages in blue circled area.